# "control data" in asp.net - asp.net - C#.Net

Tags: asp.net, controls, viewstate

I was going through code, I have seen the term "save control data", didn't get the term. Is it different from the view state data.

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

> Use control state only for small amounts of critical data that are essential for the control across postbacks. Do not use control state as an alternative to view state.